# How to change file name in loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I have files in folder /root

```
file0001
file0002
file0010
file0011
file0100
file0121
```

I have this code

```
for (( i=1; i<=1000; i++))
do
file='/root/file'$i
done
```

I need to  to change file name in loop

```
file0001 --> file1
file0010 --> file10
file0100 --> file100
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use `rename`?

Comment: I'm unsure what you need: do you need to go through all files ? Do you need to generate their name in the loop so you can work on them ? Can you just do `for file in /root/file*;` (or `/root/file[0-9]*`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) command:

```
file=$(printf "/root/file%04d" $i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trim leading zeros, simple bash script can do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line           
do           
    name=`echo $line | cut -c5- | sed 's/^[0]*//'`
    echo "file$name"
done <your_file.txt
```

result:
....
file0100->file100
file0121->file121

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cd /root
for f in file*
do
  echo mv "$f" "${f%%[0-9]*}${f#"${f%%[1-9]*}"}"
done
```

Remove the echo if OK...

Answer (score 0):

top remove trailing zeros from the number part of your filenames use:

```
rename 's/^file0*/file/' file*
```